# Как определить, что все ресурсы были показаны пользователю в браузере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня проблема в `CEF`. Все картинки, шрифты, скрипты находятся всегда в локальном хранилище, но из-за низкой производительности некоторых систем картинка может появится с большой задержкой либо с большой задержкой и дорисоваться в следующих кадрах.

Сам интерфейс в ReactJS отображается только как срабатывает функция `window.onload()`

Как можно заставить прелоадер проверить показаны ли тяжелые ресурсы (картинки в высоком качестве) на экране?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Image() конструктор. То есть нужно создавать имаджи из джаваскрипта и слушать их события "load".

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
   // execute statements here
}, false);
img.src = 'myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

[Вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) в секции "Creating an image from scratch" описано подробно. 
То есть у вас будет несколько колбэков, после вызова которых вам нужно сделать чтото. Это можно удобно сделать с помощью библиотки async, например метод [every](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#every). Там прямо в примере по сути ваш кейс:

```
var images = [];
async.every(['image1','image2','image3'], function(filePath, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
         callback();
    }, false);
    images.push(img);
    img.src = imagePath;
}, function(err, result) {
    // if result is true then every image is loaded
});
```